# Default vs Deduced template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards-compliance, template-argument-deduction

In the following :

```
template<typename Type>
struct MyClass
{
    template<typename OtherType> MyClass(const MyClass<OtherType>& x);
    template<typename OtherType = Type> void test(const MyClass<OtherType>& x);
};
```

---

In the function `test` what is done between :

**Case 1 :** The default parameter is priority : the conversion constructor `MyClass<Type>(const MyClass<OtherType>& x)` is implicitely called and `MyClass<Type>::test<Type>(const MyClass<Type>& x)` is called.

**Case 2 :** The deduced parameter is priority : `MyClass<Type>::test<Type>(const MyClass<OtherType>& x)` is called.

---

I think that the good answer is the second one, but I'm not sure. Can you confirm me that (and that this situation is well-defined by the standard) ?

---

EDIT : The test function is called by :

```
MyClass<double> d;
MyClass<unsigned int> ui;
d.test(ui); // <- So the question is : is ui implicitely 
            //    converted to MyClass<double> or not ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` will be called as

```
MyClass<double>::test(const MyClass<unsigned int> &)
```

i.e. there will be no conversion of `ui` from `MyClass<unsigned int>` to `MyClass<double>`.

A default template argument never overrides a given one. It is only used when no template argument is given and the compiler can't deduce it from the function arguments.

From the C++11 Standard:

> (§14.8.2/5) The resulting substituted and adjusted function type is used as the type of the function template for template argument deduction. If a template argument has not been deduced, its default template argument, if any, is used. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <class T, class U = double>
> void f(T t = 0, U u = 0);
> void g() {
>   f(1, ’c’);      // f<int,char>(1,’c’)
>   f(1);           // f<int,double>(1,0)
>   f();            // error: T cannot be deduced
>   f<int>();       // f<int,double>(0,0)
>   f<int,char>();  // f<int,char>(0,0)
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]