# Extract type of input parameter in templated function taking a function as parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, signature

I have this function:

```
template<typename T, int (*F)(T&)>
void DoStuff(T& s)
{
    auto an = make_any<T>(s);
    cout << _GetDataFromAny<MyStruct, F>(an);
}
```

Which needs to be called like this:

`DoStuff<MyStruct, Fun>(s);`

This works fine, however I don't like having to specify the first type, since it is part of the signature of the second parameter. I would like to be able to deduce it such that I can just call:

`DoStuff<Fun>(s);`

However, I don't know how to specify in the template that the type T needs to be deduced from the signature of the function F.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer went through a series of edits and corrections, many thanks goes to Jarod42 for his patience and help, and cigien for fruitful discussion. It is a bit longer than necessary, but I felt it is worth to keep a bit of the history. It is: the most simple / the one I would prefer / some explanation of the previous confusion. For a quick answer, read the second part.

---

*The simple*

You can use an `auto` template parameter (since C++17) for the function pointer and let `T` be deduced from the argument:

```
template<auto F, typename T>
void DoStuff(T& s)
{
    int x = F(s);
}

int foo(double&){ return 42;}

int main() {
    double x;
    DoStuff<&foo>(x);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/saeEdosYv)

---

*The "right"*

The downside of the above is that `F` and `T` are "independent". You can call `DoStuff<&foo>(y)` with eg a `std::string y;` and instantiation will only fail when calling `F`. This might lead to a unnecessarily complex error message, depending on what you actually do with `F` and `s`. To trigger the error already at the call site when a wrong `T` is passed to a `DoStuff<F>` you can use a trait to deduce the argument type of `F` and directly use that as argument type of `DoStuff`:

```
template <typename T> struct param_type;

template <typename R,typename P>
struct param_type< R(*)(P&)> {
    using type = P;
};
    
template<auto F>
void DoStuff(typename param_type<decltype(F)>::type& s)
{
    int x = F(s);  // (1)
}

int foo(double&){ return 42;}    

int main() {
    double x;
    DoStuff<foo>(x);
    std::string y; 
    DoStuff<foo>(y);  // (2) error 
}
```

Now the error that before would only happen inside the template (1) happens already in `main` (2) and the error message is much cleaner.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qqj5nWefz)

---

The "*wrong*"

Mainly as curiosity, consider this way of deducing the parameter type from the function pointer:

```
template <typename T> struct param_type;

template <typename R,typename P>
struct param_type< R(*)(P&)> {
    using type = P;
};
    
template<auto F, typename T = typename param_type<decltype(F)>::type>
void DoStuffX(T& s)
{
}

int foo(double&){ return 42;}    

int main() {
    double x;
    DoStuffX<foo>(x);
}
```

This was my original answer, but it was not actually doing what I thought it was doing. Note that I was not actually calling `F` in `DoStuff` and to my surprise this compiled:

```
int main() {
    std::string x;
    DoStuffX<foo>(x);
}
```

The reason is that the default template argument is not used when `T` can be decuded from the passed parameter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638623/default-vs-deduced-template-parameter/13638743#13638743)). That is, `DoStuffX<foo>(x);` actually instantiates `DoStuffX<foo,std::string>`. We can still get our hands on the default via:

```
int main() {
    std::string x;
    auto f_ptr = &DoStuffX<foo>;
    f_ptr(x);  // error
}
```

Now calling `DoStuffX<foo>` with a `std::string` is a compiler error, because here `DoStuffX<foo>` is instantiated as `DoStuffX<foo,double>`, the default argument is used (there is no parameter that could be used to deduce `T` when `DoStuffX` is instantiated).

Comment: `template<auto F> void DoStuffY(typename param_type<decltype(F)>::type& s)` is an alternative. No deduction at all. function pointer or regular call possible (only with expected type).

Comment: @Jarod42 That should actually be the answer. Must be something about the question, somehow I forgot everything I know and more. I will edit

Answer (score 4):

You can write a helper that deduces the argument type of a function pointer that returns `int`:

```
template<typename T>
T arg_type(int(*)(T&));
```

and then rewrite your function template slightly to take in a function pointer as a non-type template parameter, and figure out the argument type from that

```
template<auto F, typename T = decltype(arg_type(F))>
void DoStuff(T& s) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: I got into the habit of only reloading when I finished writing, its easier to see that another answer is better than mine rather than trying to compete :P

Comment: Well, this was fast! I can't yet accept the answer (SO won't let me).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah, I know what you mean. Still, it's not *competing* really; your solution is equally valid, and it would be fine to post it.

Comment: sure, competition it is not, I was joking. I just dont see what mine would add. I could try to get it without the `auto` parameter, but its getting late here

Comment: Notice that `= decltype(arg_type(F))` is rarely useful, as `T` is deduced. (useful for `auto func = &DoStuff<&Fun>;`)

Comment: `arg_type` doesn't work for all types though (those which decays such as C-arrays, functions for example).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: your solution handles correctly those edge cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 hm ok, I'll undelete, but I will need time to understand the difference

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: `auto arg_type(int (*) (char(&)[42])) -> char [42]` is illegal. cannot return C-array (even in unevaluated context). There are possible workarounds, which are more verbose, as `template<typename T>
T& arg_type(int(*)(T&));` and `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg_type(F))>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry, I am still on my first coffee, once I really understood I want to edit my answer to explain the difference. As we already realized above, it doesn't hurt to have mutliple answers with different approaches. I really thought the only difference was verbosity.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point, this won't work for all `T`s, such as `char[42]`. The OP does want the `T` explicitly though, even though it's deduced; it's being used inside the definition.

Comment: @cigien: I didn't say to remove `T`, I said that `template<auto F, typename T>
void DoStuff(T&)` would suffice for most usage. `template <auto F>
void DoStuff(std::type_identity_t<decltype(arg_type(F))>& s)` is also an interesting variant, but requires `decltype(s)` or similar to retrieve `T`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, that's true, the `T` should be deducable since it's a function parameter.

Comment: the default for the template parameter is actually rather misleading, took me some time to figure out what happens here: https://godbolt.org/z/zdP3z37hT. You can pass whatever and `T` is deduced. Removing the default makes no difference, though mine has the same issue https://godbolt.org/z/G41E7ebvh

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Hmm, that's strange. If there's a default that's not specified, then I would assume the decltype would be used instead of the argument being used for deduction. I'll take a look at this later, and see if I can figure out why this happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638743/4117728, I knew that I'll never stop learning, but that was a bit of a surprise.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Oh, nice find. I definitely didn't know, or had forgotten, that rule. Now that your answer is edited, it's much cleaner than mine.

Comment: @Makogan You should probably change the accept to the other answer. It's much cleaner, in that it points out that the helper is not needed at all, and `T` can just be deduced from the function argument. I would edit my answer, but then it would just duplicate the other one.

Comment: yeah, once i read it, it looked kinda obvious. I think you can still get your hands on the default by doing something along the line of `auto f_ptr = &DoStuff<foo>;`, have to do some experimenting

Comment: also it would be nice to enforce `T` to be the type of the parameter of `F`, though seems like OP is fine with failing only on calling `F`, or maybe they just didnt notice

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 My guess is OP didn't notice the corner cases. Hopefully, they'll read through the comments, and fix what's needed for their case.

Comment: omg only now I understand Jarod's first comment. It was all already there...

Comment: @cigien I merely implemented the solution on this answer (yours) and didn't notice any errors in the 6 places I am instantiating the template so I just assumed it was going to be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: @Makogan Yeah, that's understandable. The solution *does* work in most cases, it's just a little unwieldy, and fails on some cases. Glad you got a better solution though :)